# Method which takes two ArrayLists as parameters

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm completing an exercise which asks me to write a method called totalTax, which takes as parameters two ArrayLists, one containing houses, the other containing shops, and returns the total tax payable on all those properties. Shop, and House are two classes in my program. Each has a method which returns tax as an integer.

My solution is as follows, but I'm not sure it's the most efficient way of doing it, due to the repetition, and it doesn't compile! Is there a way to achieve the same thing, but avoid duplicate code such as I have below?

```
private int totalTax(ArrayList<Shop> list1, ArrayList<House> list2) {

    int total;

    for (int a =0; a <= list1.size() -1; a++) {

        total += list1.shopTax();

    }

    for (int a = 0; a<= list2.size() -1; a++) {

        total += list2.houseTax();

    }

    return total;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the taxes are `int` and not `double`?

Comment: This code will not compile in the first place and as such is *not* appropriate for Code Review.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution won't work since you have to access to the elements in the `List`, you're retrieving the `tax` from the list directly, as shown here:

```
total += list1.shopTax();
```

It should be

```
total += list1.get(a).shopTax();
```

Similar here:

```
total += list2.houseTax();
```

It should be:

```
total += list2.get(a).houseTax();
```

Still, this approach is using your `ArrayList` as a wrapper for an array. Another alternative could be treating the `ArrayList` as a `List`, so you will use `Iterator` rather than accessing the elements through `get` method. There are two ways to use `Iterator`:

1. Declaring the `Iterator` and initializing it with `List#iterator`:

   ```
   Iterator<Shop> shopIterator = list1.iterator();
   while (shopIterator.hasNext()) {
       Shop shop = shopIterator.next();
       total += shop.shopTax();
   }
   Iterator<House> houseIterator = list2.iterator();
   while (houseIterator.hasNext()) {
       House house = houseIterator.next();
       total += house.shopTax();
   }
   ```
2. Using enhanced `for` loop:

   ```
   for (Shop shop : list1) {
       total += shop.shopTax();
   }
   for (House house : list2) {
       total += house.houseTax();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

In terms of DRY code, you can do better if you alter your class hierarchy such that House and Shop both implement a shared interface. Consider the following:

```
public interface Taxable{
    public int getTax();
}

public class House implements Taxable{

    //Other code you've written for House

    public int getTax(){
        return houseTax();
    }
}

public class Shop implements Taxable{

    //Other code you've written for Shop

    public int getTax(){
        return shopTax();
    }
}
```

From there you can take in a single ArrayList of Taxables (containing both houses and shops) and total their taxes without repeating yourself.

```
private int totalTax(ArrayList<? extends Taxable> lst) {
    int total;
    for (Taxable t : lst) {
        total += t.getTax();
    }
    return total;
}
```

If you absolutely must take two ArrayLists as parameters, you can still not repeat yourself creating this method, relying on the above method as its helper.

```
private int totalTax(ArrayList<House> list1, ArrayList<Shop> list2){
    return totalTax(list1) + totalTax(list2)
}
```

Comment: from the question " which takes as parameters two ArrayLists"

Comment: Now addressed. It seems weird to take two arraylists when you're treating the elements from both the same, but I suppose there must be design reasons.

Comment: Well, you're only treating them the same because you have introduced an interface. We have no way of knowing if the code for Shop and House implement any interface or are open to change.

Answer (score 0):

**To answer the specific problems with the code not compiling**

See comments below:

```
class Shop {
    int tax;
    int shopTax() { return tax; }
}
class House {
    int tax;
    int houseTax() { return tax; }
}
private int totalTax(ArrayList<Shop> list1, ArrayList<House> list2) {
    // Need to initialize total to 0
    int total = 0;

    for (int a =0; a <= list1.size() -1; a++) {
        // Need to get the element from the list first
        Shop shop = list1.get(a);
        total += shop.shopTax();
    }

    for (int a = 0; a<= list2.size() -1; a++) {
        // Need to get the element from the list first
        House house = list2.get(a);
        total += house.houseTax();
    }
    return total;
}
```

**To answer "Is there a way to achieve the same thing, but avoid duplicate code such as I have below?"**

```
interface Taxable {
    double getTax();
}

class Shop implements Taxable {
    public double getTax() {
        return 0d;
    }
}

class House implements Taxable {
    public double getTax() {
        return 0d;
    }
}

public double totalTax(List<Taxable> thingsToTax) {
    double total = 0;
    for (Taxable taxable : thingsToTax) {
        total += taxable.getTax();
    }
    return total;
}
```

**Updated**

I missed the part where 'the method must take two parameters'.  So adding this part:

```
public double totalTax(List<Taxable> thingsToTax, List<Taxable> otherThingsToTax) {
    return totalTax(thingsToTax) + totalTax(otherThingsToTax);
}
```

This also uses `double` instead of `int` which I have to imagine is more appropriate.  Otherwise, feel free to use `int` if still desired.

Comment: He says he has to use a method with 2 List parameters .. guess you could add them all to a list of taxable then call this

Answer (score -1):

Something like this is little bit efficient :

```
private int totalTax(ArrayList<Shop> list1, ArrayList<House> list2) {

 int total = 0;
 int miSize = Math.min(list1.size(), list2.size());

 for (int a = 0; a < minSize; a++)
    total += list1.get(a).shopTax() + list2.get(a).houseTax();


 if(list1.size() > minSize)
    for (int a = minSize; a < list1.size(); a++)
        total += list1.get(a).shopTax();
 else
    for (int a = minSize; a < list2.size(); a++)
        total += list2.get(a).shopTax();


 return total;
}
```